# C product of three consecutive numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

I was trying to solve this tricky question, but for some reason my code is doing something wrong... I don't exactly know why, but I'll try to explain as much as I can.

> **Consecutive products:** 
>   Write a program that reads a positive integer
>   from standard input and verifies if it's equal to the product of three
>   natural and consecutive numbers. For example, the number 120 is equal
>   to 4x5x6, as for number 90 there aren't any three consecutive natural
>   numbers whose product is 90. Your program should generate as output
>   'S' if there are 3 consecutive natural numbers whose product is the
>   value read, or 'N' if none.

```
Input

120

Expected Output

"S"


Input

60

Expected Output

"S"


Input

80

Expected Output

"N"


Input

120

Expected Output

"S"
```

And this is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int int1,i,count=10,j,k,w=0;
    scanf("%i",&int1);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= count+1; ++j)
        {
            for ( k = 1; k <= count+2; ++k)
            {
                if ((i==j+1 && i==k+2) && (i*j*k==int1)){
                    w=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (w==0)
    {
        printf("N");
    }
    else{
        printf("S");
    }
}
```

So basically what this does is I have 3 loops that will generate random numbers in a `k*i*j` form... and it checks if we are getting what we want(the product of three natural and consecutive numbers) . This is for an assignment.

Comment: Your process doesn't seem effective, try finding prime factors and then check whether consecutive numbers can be found using different combinations of multiples.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What do you expect that your program doesn't output? It appears to work for the examples you gave.

Comment: yeah i know, thats exactly why I was very confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your code. Please let me know if the problem still exists. The change made is exactly as WDS said.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int int1,i,count=10,j,k,w=0,comp;
scanf("%i",&int1);
for (i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
{
    comp = i*(i+1)*(i+2);
    if(comp==int1)
    {
        w = 1;
    }
}
if (w==0)
{
    printf("N");
}
else
{
    printf("S");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code won't work as is, but is a good way to give hints without saying the final answer

Answer (score 4):

You don't need 3 loops. One trival approach would be:

```
int test(int num)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        int product = i * (i + 1) * (i + 2);
        if ( product == num )
            return true;
        else if (product > num)
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The way you declared the variables is only be correct for C++ right?

Comment: It might work with C99 :). Kidding, I'm come from C++ background, hence the variables declared as needed. But seriously, in C99, they are legal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99

Comment: This code could produce inaccurate results if the multiplication overflows, which it will if `num` is greater then the greatest number that produces an `S` output and fits in the data type.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I went over your case, and couldn't find how this code can produce inaccurate result. The test product==num still works so there is no change to recognize N as S. The loop terminates by the for condition (i < num) instead of (product > num). (Now if negative num is another story, but I assume that the caller catches that condition :)) Can you elaborate on how the code can break?

Comment: For high `num` the product will overflow. Given how most compilers deal with overflow the product will become negative. Then as `i` grows bigger the product will turn positive again and might happen to become `num`. Try with `num=139154728` which should not return true for `i=2058`, but it does (assuming 32 bit `int`). The real value of `2058*2059*2060` is `8729089320` and doesn't fit in a 32 bit integer.

Comment: If num=139154729, the loop would break at i=518 (product=518*519*520=139797840, which is greater than n) and returns false. It does not reach 2058. But I see your point. Robust code should handle corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add the algorithm tag on this question.  That said, my approach would be to consider what the product of 3 consecutive numbers is.  You could write it as x * (x+1) * (x+2).  But there is a better way.

Write it as (x-1) * x * (x+1).  Then multiply and simplify.  The result is x^3-x.

Now for any given number, start a single loop on x from x = 2 (because if x=1 then x-1=0 and this will never be a solution) and incrementing by 1 each loop.  Check on each loop for a match with the input number.  If it is a match, return true.  If it is not a match and exceeds the input number return false.  If it is not a match and is less than the input number, loop again.

Comment: To improve even further one could solve the equation `x^3 -x = num` and see if the result is an integer. That would be on O(1) solution.